# Visualforce page not working in lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, page-layout

I have added this visualforce page as a section on page layout, this works in classic, but nothing gets displayed in lightning experience. What needs to be done so that this works in lightning experience.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" action="{!showMessage}" extensions="OpportunityExtension">
    <apex:outputText value="Message One." rendered="{!displayMessage}"/>
    <apex:outputText value="Message Two." rendered="{!NOT(displayMessage)}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: any errors when loading?

Comment: This should work just fine in LEX. Check your developer consoles (both F12 in the browser, plus "Your Name" > Developer Console in Salesforce). I presume you should get some sort of message somewhere if there's an error.

Comment: error in chrome : Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension: https://sfdc.azureedge.net *.cs88.visual.force.com https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/".

Comment: error in internet explorer : Access is denied
A script tried to access data from a source other than the host of the current page. The Same Origin Policy followed by Internet Explorer and other browsers allows scripts to access data only from sources with the same scheme, host, and port of the URL of the current page.  
For example, if the current page is https://employees.mycompany.com, you can't access data from the following URLs:  
http://data.contoso.com, because it is using HTTP instead of HTTPS.